# How do I store data from two components in a single object/state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a joystick app with two joystick components in react. I want to get there coordinates at a single place in the parent component "App.js" which is going to be updated every certain interval and then those coordinates are to be sent over socket.io to a server.
I have tried many things like using callback passed to the joystick and then setting state from the parent component. But it's not working. The values are getting stored separately.
I have beginner knowledge of reactjs.

Part of App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            connection: 'close',
            view: "joystick",
            logs: [],
            coordinates: {A: {x:0, y:0},
            B: {x:0, y:0}}
        }

        this.socket = socketIOClient({'reconnectionAttempts': 1,});
    }

    getJoystickValue = (coords) => {
        const k = Object.keys(coords)[0]
        this.setState({coordinates[k]: coords[k]})

    }

render () {
<div className="container">
                    <Header status={this.state.connection} viewToggle={this.toggleView}></Header>
                    <div className="pad">
                        <Joystick jname="A" getValues={this.getJoystickValue} socketIO={this.socket}></Joystick>
                        <Log logText={this.state.logs}></Log>
                        <Joystick jname="B" getValues={this.getJoystickValue} socketIO={this.socket}></Joystick>              

                    </div>
                </div>
}
}
```

Joystick.js

```
class Joystick extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.maxDiff = 50;
        this.dragStart = null;
        this.currentPos = { x: 0, y: 0 };
        this.stick = React.createRef();
        this.stickArea = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.stick.current.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleMouseDown);
        this.stick.current.addEventListener('touchstart', this.handleMouseDown);
        this.stickArea.current.addEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMouseMove);
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.handleMouseUp);
        this.stickArea.current.addEventListener('touchmove', this.handleMouseMove);
        this.stickArea.current.addEventListener('touchend', this.handleMouseUp);


        setInterval(() => {
           this.props.getValues(this.getPosition());
        }, 1500);

    }


    getPosition = () => {
        const nm = this.props.jname;
        const coords = {};
        coords[nm] = this.currentPos;
        return coords;
    }

    checkConstraints = (touchArray) => {
      let touch = null;
      const constraints = this.stickArea.current.getBoundingClientRect();
      for (const point of touchArray) {
         if ((point.clientX < constraints.right && point.clientX > constraints.left)
              && (point.clientY < constraints.bottom && point.clientY > constraints.top)) {
                touch = point
         }
      }

      if (touch) {
        return touch;
      }
      return null;

    }

    handleMouseDown = (event) => {
        this.stick.current.style.transition = '0s';
        if (event.changedTouches) {
            this.dragStart = {
              x: event.changedTouches[0].clientX,
              y: event.changedTouches[0].clientY,
            };
            return;
          }
          this.dragStart = {
            x: event.clientX,
            y: event.clientY,
          };
        };

    handleMouseMove = (event) => {
        if (this.dragStart === null) return;
        event.preventDefault();

        const endtouch = new Event('touchend', {
          view: window,
          bubbles: true,
          cancelable: true
        });

        if (event.changedTouches) {
          const p = this.checkConstraints(event.changedTouches);
          if (!p) {
            this.stick.current.dispatchEvent(endtouch);
            return;
          }
          event.clientX = p.clientX;
          event.clientY = p.clientY;
        }

        const xDiff = event.clientX - this.dragStart.x;
        const yDiff = event.clientY - this.dragStart.y;
        const angle = Math.atan2(yDiff, xDiff);
            const distance = Math.min(this.maxDiff, Math.hypot(xDiff, yDiff));
            const xNew = distance * Math.cos(angle);
            const yNew = distance * Math.sin(angle);
        this.stick.current.style.transform = `translate3d(${xNew}px, ${yNew}px, 0px)`;
        this.currentPos = { x: xNew, y: -yNew };

      };

    handleMouseUp = (event) => {
        if (this.dragStart === null) return;
        this.stick.current.style.transition = '.2s';
        this.stick.current.style.transform = `translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)`;
        this.dragStart = null;
        this.currentPos = { x: 0, y: 0 };
      };


    render () {
        return (
            <div className="stick-area" ref={this.stickArea}>
            <div id={this.props.jname} className="base">
                <div className="stick" ref={this.stick}></div>
            </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Joystick;
```

EDIT: correction by  Siva Kondapi Venkata is working finely but when sent over socket.io using emit it is getting empty coordinates object in between. 
[Values as received by server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6Gua.png)

Comment: suspecting the setState in getJoystickValue, Can you try replacing with "getJoystickValue = coords => this.setState({ coordinates: {...this.state.coordinates, ...coords} })" ?

Comment: Glad to hear that! @Anshul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the getJoystickValue method as below. Take the current state value of coordinates, merge the new data and update the state.

```
getJoystickValue = coords => 
    this.setState({ coordinates: {...this.state.coordinates, ...coords} })
```

Comment: The coordinates from two joysticks are getting stored in same object but when emitted over socket to server, there is an empty coordinates object at regular interval. Can you tell me why is this so. `setInterval(()=> {
            if (this.socket.connected) {
                this.emit('coords', this.coordinates);
            }
        }, 100)`

Comment: @AnshulBansal, Not sure why the empty events are coming, But how about ignoring the empty events? either do `if (this.socket.connect && (not empty coords))` or dont call setState in getJoystickValue when empty. Hope this works for your scenario. Anyways this problem seems different from the actual question right?

Comment: Sorry about not adding this problem to another question. But this is only working when I set the time interval of emit function about half the time interval at which setInterval() in Joystick component is working.